# what does opcode==0 signify?

Tags: javascript, web-services, temenos-quantum

I am using Kony studio for an app development. I have done the login validation using Eclipse to code for creating web services to connect to the oracle10g database. But on the front end I'm getting an error, when I'm trying to connect the front end to the web service. 
The status==400 is getting validated but I'm not getting opcode as 0, instead its going in the else statement and giving an error alert. This is the Javascript code for connecting to the web service.
Please help. What does opstatus==0 signify?

```
function GetLogin()
{



var Userid =login.txtloginuname.text;
var Password = login.txtloginpass.text;

var inputParamsLogin={serviceID:"servicelogin",uname:Userid,pass:Password}


if (Userid!=null && Userid!="" && Password!="" && Password!=null)
  {

  appmiddlewareinvokerasync(inputParamsLogin,loginCallBackresponse);
  }
  else
  {
        var alert_seq5_act0 = kony.ui.Alert(
              {
            "message": "Please Enter User name and password",
            "alertType": constants.ALERT_TYPE_ERROR,
            "alertTitle": "",
            "yesLabel": "OK",
            "noLabel": "",
            "alertIcon": "",
            "alertHandler": null
        }, {});
        kony.application.dismissLoadingScreen();
   }

function loginCallBackresponse(status,loginResults)
{
        if(status==400)
        {
        alert("productResults");
            if(loginResults.opstatus==0)
            {
             alert("inside opstatus");

            else
            {
            var alert_seq5_act0 = kony.ui.Alert({"message": "Service      Failed:"+loginResults.errmsg,
            "alertType": constants.ALERT_TYPE_ERROR,
            "alertTitle": "",
            "yesLabel": "OK",
            "noLabel": "",
            "alertIcon": "",
            "alertHandler": null}, {});
            kony.application.dismissLoadingScreen();
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

I am getting the alert "product results" but unable to get the alert "inside opstatus".
Instead I'm getting "service failed alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the opstatus is 0, it indicates that the service call is a success while a non-zero value indicates a failure.**

Please read the following that gives you more info on network call in Kony

The following is the description of the parameters associated with network call in kony:

status - an integer value - indicating the status

The following are the various status returned:

100 - network call initiated successfully - resultset will not be available and it is nil.
200 - network is in progress (when you start receiving the 1st byte) - resultset will not be available and it is nil.
300 - network call canceled - resultset will not be available and it is nil.
400 - network call is finished (gets called in both success and failure scenarios - actual state can be queried using opstatus in the resultset.
Note: On Mobile Web, the callback function is always invoked with a status of 400. Other intermediate status codes are not applicable on Mobile Web.

resulttable - a Object with key-value pairs - follows the same structure (opstatus, errcode, errmsg along with the actual network returned data)
This represents the Object returned by the service. This Object contains three values:

opstatus

errcode

errmsg.

If the opstatus is 0, it indicates that the service call is a success while a non-zero value indicates a failure.

If the opstatus is a non-zero value, it is captured in errcode. The following are the possible error codes:

1000- Unknown Error while connecting (If the platform cannot differentiate between the various kinds of network errors, the platform reports this error code by default).
1011 - Device has no WIFI or mobile connectivity. Please try the operation after establishing connectivity.
1012 - Request Failed.
1013 - Middleware returned invalid JSON string.
1014 - Request timed out.
1015 - Cannot find host.
1016 - Cannot connect to host.
1200 - SSL - Certificate related error codes.
The error message corresponding to each error code is captured in the errmsg parameter.

Comment: After publishing my created service and obtaining this url, I put the url in chrome: http://<ip-address>:8081/admin/direct. I got the following error:                                                 Step: PrepareArchive<BR/>Step: PrepareArchive failed(Message : error in opening zip file)<BR/>Start roll back...<BR/>Rollback Step: PrepareArchive<BR/>Rollback Step: PrepareArchive failed(Message : error in opening zip file)<BR/>                                    How do I solve it???

Comment: http://<ip-address>:8081/admin/direct should give kony moddleware console. I feel that the middle ware is not configured correctly. There will a middleware.log file. Please check the log in that.

Comment: where will I find this file and what do I check in it? I'm new to kony

Comment: you have tomcat as middle ware ?Please look into the middleware.log of your tom cat. To find this check the middleware-log4j.properties in tomcat middleware-bootconfig folder. In that check the log4j.appender.file.File will give the path towards middleware.log

Comment: I have another question, I am creating a native android app using kony. I have a text box for password. How can I set the properties such that when text is entered its seen as just dots. I am unable to find any such option

Comment: There is a property called secureTextEntry, make this true for password field. Look into the following link for more updates and discussion on Kony IDE. http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=4981807&trk=groups_item_detail-h-logo&goback=%2Egmr_4981807

Comment: I have asked my doubts on the link you mentioned above, but the submission is pending.

Comment: I created a web service to insert data in the database. I am able to insert it and it appears in the database too, but my opstatus is something other than 0. Im getting an error code of 5001. what does it mean?